# When I call C().__init__() from class D, why the result of C().__init__() gets printed twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
class M(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("M constructor")
        super().__init__()


class F(M):
    def __init__(self):
        print("F constructor")
        super().__init__()


class C(F):
    def __init__(self):

        print("C constructor")
        super().__init__()

class D(C,F):
    def __init__(self):
        print("D constructor")
        C().__init__()


D()
```

Output is:

```
D constructor
C constructor
F constructor
M constructor
C constructor
F constructor
M constructor
```

I was expecting:

```
D constructor
C constructor
F constructor
M constructor
```

Comment: If you called `super().__init__()` in `D` you'd get the expected output.

Comment: Because `D` created a *new* instance of `C`, distinct from `self`.

Comment: I think what you wanted was `C.__init__(self)`. This calls the `__init__()` method from `C` without creating a new instance.

Comment: ok So is it like creating C() inside D class gives o/p:
C constructor
F constructor
M Constructor

and C().init() gives o/p as :
C constructor
F constructor
M Constructor

is it somethign like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C().__init__()` is effectively equivalent to:

```
temp = C()
temp.__init__()
```

When calling `C()`, the `__init__()` method in the `C` class is called automatically, so it prints `C constructor` and also calls all the parent constructors.

Then you call the `__init__()` method explicitly, so it repeats this process.

If you just want to call the `C` constructor without creating a temporary instance, use `C.__init__(self)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two objects in your program: a `D` object, and a `C` object (which you create in the `D` constructor, initialize twice by manually calling `__init__()` after creating the instance, and then throw away).

If you want to call `C`'s initializer explicitly in `D`'s initializer (rather than using `super()`) the correct way to do that is:

```
C.__init__(self)
```